# jQuery - How to send ajax post on ajax post page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to send ajax post on ajax posted page.

index.php has

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",datatype:"json", url: "/notification.php",      
data: "kime=karaakce&tur=konuyayorum&postid=2020",
success: function(html){
}
});
```

notification.php has same function but posts to track.php

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",datatype:"json", url: "/track.php",      
data: "kime=karaakce&tur=konuyayorum&postid=2020",
success: function(html){
}
});
```

However, notification.php doesnt send the ajax post. How can I make it run ?

Comment: Does notification.php include jQuery?

Comment: jquery library is not included in notification.php page

Comment: Then `$.ajax` is not defined.

Comment: call the second ajax in the first page

Comment: So if I use load function on index.php, will it work ? because jquery is included in index.php,

Comment: If you want to make two requests you can just add the extra ajax call in the `success` function.

Comment: I need to run it on notification page, because it takes some values from mysql and has if else statements to post or not.

Comment: If you want to use `$.ajax` or any `$.`-function, you will need to have jQuery.
If you want to load and execute a script using jQuery use `$.loadScript("/script.js");`.

Comment: Would it cause problems if I use <iframe src="track.php?kime=karaakce&tur=konuyayorum&postid=2020"> on notification page ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you cannot run the jquery code even if you include it in your notification.php file. That is because jquery runs only in browser, not at backend. So unless you "physically" open the notification.php page in browser the jquery won't run.

So to address your issue you'll have to chain the success response from one php file to next.

eg:
Data from index.php ---> notification.php ---> index.php ---> track.php
(Although a very crude approach)

Here is the code that can achieve this.

index.php file

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    datatype:"json", 
    url: "/notification.php",      
    data: {
            kime=karaakce,
            tur=konuyayorum,
            postid=2020
          }
    success: function(responseData){
           $.ajax({ 
                     type: "POST",
                     datatype:"json", 
                     url: "/track.php",      
                     data: {
                              kime=karaakce,
                              tur=konuyayorum,
                              postid=2020
                     }
                     success: function(html){
                        // This is your final success 
                  }
               });
   }
});
```

Your notification.php file should return a JSON data which you can use to send it to the next request. It will come in 'responseData' object.